# How to prevent page break between listing caption and code?

Tags: listings, page-breaking

How to prevent page break between listing caption and code (see the picture)?

[image: screenshot]

Minimal example illustrating issue:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
    frame=top,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=10pt,
    tabsize=4,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=t,
    mathescape=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=0pt,
    framexbottommargin=5pt,
    framextopmargin=5pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    upquote=true
}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\textbf{#1#2}#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={sf},labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Listing}

\fontsize{10}{12pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{XXX}

X \\
X \\
X \\

\section{XXX}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=xxx]
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=xxx]
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Just for clarification: I don't want to disable breaking listings.

Answer (score 4):

In your case you can just add option `float` to the call of the second listing.  Then the listing can float over pages. In your case the complete second listing is moved to page two.

MWE (see changed line marked with `<=======`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}

\usepackage[a4paper, left=3.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, top=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}

\lstset{
    frame=top,
    stepnumber=1,
    numbersep=10pt,
    tabsize=4,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=t,
    mathescape=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    xleftmargin=17pt,
    framexleftmargin=17pt,
    framexrightmargin=0pt,
    framexbottommargin=5pt,
    framextopmargin=5pt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    upquote=true
}

\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\textbf{#1#2}#3}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,singlelinecheck=false, margin=0pt, font={sf},labelsep=space,labelfont=bf}

\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Listing}

\fontsize{10}{12pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{XXX}

X \\
X \\
X \\

\section{XXX}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption=xxx]
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}[float,caption=xxx] % <=================== added float
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: result of mwe]